# Symfony 4: creating form for an entity that has relationships with multiple entities

Tags: forms, entity, symfony4

I'm trying make a site that let users custom build a car. A new instance of car model will be created when a user started. In the car model, the user can add different parts and define custom color to it. And the name of the parts will be loaded a table that stores all the names. So it will look like 'belt -> brown', 'left-door -> red'.

Right now I have finish creating the entities and relationship. They are the CarModel, ModelPart and PartName entities:

CarModel entity

```
class CarModel
{
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ModelPart", inversedBy="carModels") 
    */
    private $modelParts;
}
```

ModelPart entity

```
class ModelPart
{
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CarModel", mappedBy="modelParts")
    */
    private $carModels;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PartName")
    */
    private $partName;

    // @var string
    private $color;
}
```

PartName entity

```
class PartName
{
    private $id;

    private $name;

    private $modelPart
}
```

But I couldn't figure out enter them from a form.

CarModelType form

```
class CarModelType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('part_name', EntityType::class, [
                 'class' => partName::class,
                 'choice_label' => 'name'
           ])
            ->add('color', TextType::class)            
        ;
    }
```

I got the error message:

> Neither the property "part_name" nor one of the methods "getPartName()", "partName()", "isPartName()", "hasPartName()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\CarModel".

Comment: Do you have public getters/setters in your `CarModel` entity? The Form component uses getters and setters for property access.

Comment: Yes I do, I think the problem is that CarModel did not have a direct connection with PartName, but I'm trying to get it in one form

Comment: You could embed the form `ModelPartType` in your form `CarModelType`.